# Marshal Union(C ) with a Struct which contains an Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, union, marshalling

I try to Marshal a unmanaged c++ dll in c#, but the marshaller fails when creating my union.

Why does this code fail?

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct StructWithArray
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
        public int[] MySimpleArray;
        //More Stuff
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct Union
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int Int; //Or anything else
        [FieldOffset(0), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        public StructWithArray MyStructWithArray;
        //More Structs
    }
```

And then constructing the Union:

```
Union MyUnion = new Union();
```

It fails if I run the code with the following Message: (Translated)

> {"The Type "Union" of the Assembly [...] could not be loaded because it contained an Objectfield at Offset 0, which is not aligned correctly or got overlapped by a field which isnt a ObjectField":"Union"}

Any Suggestions?

Ps: The original code is heavily simplified to show only the Problem. There are much more Structs, and the Union is also contained by another Struct.

Comment: Possibly an Pack issue. Try first adding attribute Pack=4 to first structure. Do you have #pragma pack in your header files for those struct.

Comment: I dont have a #pragma in the header file. And in this code i havent even loaded the dll. this example is enough to get the error. Pack=1, Pack=4 tested, Fixed Size Tested, copying the Array directly to the union tested, all with the same result.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190079/incorrectly-aligned-or-overlapped-by-a-non-object-field-error It seems that you solution is to replace first structure with     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct StructWithArray
    {int a;int b;
        //More Stuff
    }

Comment: Yes, I think this is the only workaround. Or for native structures, i can use "unsafe" and "fixed array", but as i said, this only works for native structures like int, uint etc.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `MySimpleArray` as a fixed unsafe array:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct StructWithArray
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public fixed int MySimpleArray[2];
    //More Stuff
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Union
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Int; //Or anything else
    [FieldOffset(0), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public StructWithArray MyStructWithArray;
    //More Structs
}
```

Comment: Sadly the keyword "fixed" only works with ValueTypes like ints, bytes etc. Assuming I have an array of other structures, the "fixed" keyword doesn't work anymore.