# Dealing With Odd FieldOffset

Tags: c#, c++, struct, pinvoke, offset

I'm trying port the following C++ struct to C#.

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct FatBootSectorStruct {
    UCHAR  BS_jmpBoot[3];          // 0
    UCHAR  BS_OEMName[8];          // 3
    USHORT BPB_BytsPerSec;         // 11
    UCHAR  BPB_SecPerClus;         // 13
    USHORT BPB_RsvdSecCnt;         // 14
    UCHAR  BPB_NumFATs;            // 16
    USHORT BPB_RootEntCnt;         // 17
    USHORT BPB_TotSec16;           // 19
    UCHAR  BPB_Media;              // 21
    USHORT BPB_FATSz16;            // 22
    USHORT BPB_SecPerTrk;          // 24
    USHORT BPB_NumHeads;           // 26
    ULONG  BPB_HiddSec;            // 28
    ULONG  BPB_TotSec32;           // 32
    union {
        struct {
            UCHAR  BS_DrvNum;          // 36
            UCHAR  BS_Reserved1;       // 37
            UCHAR  BS_BootSig;         // 38
            ULONG  BS_VolID;           // 39
            UCHAR  BS_VolLab[11];      // 43
            UCHAR  BS_FilSysType[8];   // 54
            UCHAR  BS_Reserved2[448];  // 62
        } Fat16;
        struct {
            ULONG  BPB_FATSz32;        // 36
            USHORT BPB_ExtFlags;       // 40
            USHORT BPB_FSVer;          // 42
            ULONG  BPB_RootClus;       // 44
            USHORT BPB_FSInfo;         // 48
            USHORT BPB_BkBootSec;      // 50
            UCHAR  BPB_Reserved[12];   // 52
            UCHAR  BS_DrvNum;          // 64
            UCHAR  BS_Reserved1;       // 65
            UCHAR  BS_BootSig;         // 66
            ULONG  BS_VolID;           // 67
            UCHAR  BS_VolLab[11];      // 71
            UCHAR  BS_FilSysType[8];   // 82
            UCHAR  BPB_Reserved2[420]; // 90
        } Fat32;
    };
    USHORT Signature;              // 510
};
```

This is what I have:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 512, Pack=1)]
internal struct FATBootSector
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte[] BS_jmpBoot; // 0
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte[] BS_OEMName; // 3
    [FieldOffset(11)]
    public ushort BPB_BytsPerSec; // 11
    [FieldOffset(13)]
    public byte BPB_SecPerClus; // 13
    [FieldOffset(14)]
    public ushort BPB_RsvdSecCnt; // 14
    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public byte BPB_NumFATs; // 16
    [FieldOffset(17)]
    public ushort BPB_RootEntCnt; // 17
    [FieldOffset(19)]
    public ushort BPB_TotSec16; // 19
    [FieldOffset(21)]
    public byte BPB_Media; // 21
    [FieldOffset(22)]
    public ushort BPB_FATSz16; // 22
    [FieldOffset(24)]
    public ushort BPB_SecPerTrk; // 24
    [FieldOffset(26)]
    public ushort BPB_NumHeads; // 26
    [FieldOffset(28)]
    public ulong BPB_HiddSec; // 28
    [FieldOffset(32)]
    public ulong BPB_TotSec32; // 32

    // FAT16
    [FieldOffset(36)]
    public byte FAT16_BS_DrvNum; // 36
    [FieldOffset(37)]
    public byte FAT16_BS_Reserved1; // 37
    [FieldOffset(38)]
    public byte FAT16_BS_BootSig; // 38
    [FieldOffset(39)]
    public ulong FAT16_BS_VolID; // 39
    [FieldOffset(43)]
    public byte[] FAT16_BS_VolLab; // 43
    [FieldOffset(54)]
    public byte[] FAT16_BS_FilSysType; // 54
    [FieldOffset(62)]
    public byte[] FAT16_BS_Reserved2; // 62

    // FAT32
    [FieldOffset(36)]
    public ulong FAT32_BPB_FATSz32; // 36
    [FieldOffset(40)]
    public ushort FAT32_BPB_ExtFlags; // 40
    [FieldOffset(42)]
    public ushort FAT32_BPB_FSVer; // 42
    [FieldOffset(44)]
    public ulong FAT32_BPB_RootClus; // 44
    [FieldOffset(48)]
    public ushort FAT32_BPB_FSInfo; // 48
    [FieldOffset(50)]
    public ushort FAT32_BPB_BkBootSec; // 50
    [FieldOffset(52)]
    public byte[] FAT32_BPB_Reserved; // 52
    [FieldOffset(64)]
    public byte FAT32_BS_DrvNum; // 64
    [FieldOffset(65)]
    public byte FAT32_BS_Reserved1; // 65
    [FieldOffset(66)]
    public byte FAT32_BS_BootSig; // 66
    [FieldOffset(67)]
    public byte FAT32_BS_VolID; // 67
    [FieldOffset(71)]
    public byte[] BS_VolLab; // 71
    [FieldOffset(82)]
    public byte[] FAT32_BS_FilSysType; // 82
    [FieldOffset(90)]
    public byte[] FAT32_BPB_Reserved2; // 90

    [FieldOffset(510)]
    public ushort Signature;

}
```

The problem lies in field offset 0 and 3. When I try to load the structure in C#, I get `Could not load type 'FATBootSector' from assembly 'xxxx' because it contains an object field at offset 3 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.`. I came across [this previous question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190079/incorrectly-aligned-or-overlapped-by-a-non-object-field-error) but that doesn't seem to help.

I've also tried changing it into a sequential structure like below:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 512, Pack=1, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
internal struct FATBootSector
{

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte BS_jmpBoot0; // 0
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte BS_jmpBoot1; // 0
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte BS_jmpBoot2; // 0

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst=8)]
    public string BS_OEMName; // 3
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort BPB_BytsPerSec; // 11
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte BPB_SecPerClus; // 13
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort BPB_RsvdSecCnt; // 14
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte BPB_NumFATs; // 16
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort BPB_RootEntCnt; // 17
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort BPB_TotSec16; // 19
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte BPB_Media; // 21
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort BPB_FATSz16; // 22
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort BPB_SecPerTrk; // 24
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort BPB_NumHeads; // 26
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public ulong BPB_HiddSec; // 28
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public ulong BPB_TotSec32; // 32

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 474)]
    public byte[] FAT1632Info;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort Signature;

}
```

And I'm using the following code to get the structure:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool ReadFile(IntPtr hFile, [Out] IntPtr lpBuffer, uint nNumberOfBytesToRead, out uint lpNumberOfBytesRead, [In] ref System.Threading.NativeOverlapped lpOverlapped);

public bool GetPartitionDetails()
{
        uint BytesRead;

        IntPtr BootSectorPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(512);
        PInvoke.FATBootSector BootSector;

        System.Threading.NativeOverlapped Overlapped = new System.Threading.NativeOverlapped();

        bool ret = PInvoke.ReadFile(this.Handle, BootSectorPtr, (uint)512, out BytesRead, ref Overlapped);

        BootSector = (PInvoke.FATBootSector)Marshal.PtrToStructure(BootSectorPtr, typeof(PInvoke.FATBootSector)); // causes access violation

        return true;
}
```

I'm hoping I don't have to, but the only alternative I can think of is iterating through the memory using the `IntPtr`. Any ideas?

Comment: Does `public byte[] BS_jmpBoot;` declare an array of unknown size, or a pointer to an array, in C#?

Comment: I've tried specifying the size using ``MarshalAs``, fixed byte, and as shown above, splitting it up into 3 separate bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few problems here. First of all you are abusing `FieldOffset`. You use that when the compiler cannot layout the struct for you. Invariably that is when you have a union. Don't use `FieldOffset` here. And certainly don't specify the size up front. Again, let the compiler do that. Check it against the native version.

Then you handle the arrays incorrectly. You don't need `fixed`, but you do need to say how long the arrays are. The start of the struct should look like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
internal struct FATBootSector
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public byte[] BS_jmpBoot;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public byte[] BS_OEMName;
    ....
}
```

The rest of your problems are caused by erroneous type conversions. `ULONG` in C++ is a 4 byte unsigned type. That's `uint` in C#. You using `ulong` which is 8 bytes wide.

Here's a version of the struct which will at least avoid the access violations:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
internal struct FATBootSector
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public byte[] BS_jmpBoot; 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public byte[] BS_OEMName; 
    public ushort BPB_BytsPerSec;
    public byte BPB_SecPerClus; 
    public ushort BPB_RsvdSecCnt;
    public byte BPB_NumFATs; 
    public ushort BPB_RootEntCnt;
    public ushort BPB_TotSec16; 
    public byte BPB_Media; 
    public ushort BPB_FATSz16;
    public ushort BPB_SecPerTrk;
    public ushort BPB_NumHeads;
    public uint BPB_HiddSec; 
    public uint BPB_TotSec32; 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 474)]
    public byte[] FAT1632Info;
    public ushort Signature;
}
```

To translate the FAT16/FAT32 union, you may need to use `fixed`. Or alternatively have two `FATBootSector` types. One for FAT16 and one for FAT32.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the `IntPtr` to fill out the structure fields. The following code walks through the memory and get each field.

```
    internal struct FATBootSector
    {
        public byte[] BS_jmpBoot; // 0
        public string BS_OEMName; // 3
        public ushort BytesPerSector; // 11
        public byte SectorsPerCluster; // 13
        public ushort ReservedSectors; // 14
        public byte NumberOfFATs; // 16
        public ushort RootEntries; // 17
        public ushort TotalSectors16; // 19
        public byte MediaDescriptor; // 21
        public ushort SectorsPerFAT; // 22
        public ushort SectorsPerTrack; // 24
        public ushort Heads; // 26
        public uint HiddenSectors; // 28
        public uint TotalSectors32; // 32

        public FAT1632Info FAT1632Info;

        public ushort Signature;

        public FATBootSector(IntPtr ptr)
        {
            int i;

            this.BS_jmpBoot = new byte[3];

            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                this.BS_jmpBoot[i] = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr);
                ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);
            }

            StringBuilder oemInfo = new StringBuilder(8);

            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                char c = (char)Marshal.ReadByte(ptr);
                oemInfo.Append(c);
                ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);
            }

            this.BS_OEMName = oemInfo.ToString();

            this.BytesPerSector = (ushort)Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 2);

            this.SectorsPerCluster = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);

            this.ReservedSectors = (ushort)Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 2);

            this.NumberOfFATs = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);

            this.RootEntries = (ushort)Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 2);

            this.TotalSectors16 = (ushort)Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 2);

            this.MediaDescriptor = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);

            this.SectorsPerFAT = (ushort)Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 2);

            this.SectorsPerTrack = (ushort)Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 2);

            this.Heads = (ushort)Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 2);

            this.HiddenSectors = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 4);

            this.TotalSectors32 = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 4);

            this.FAT1632Info = new PInvoke.FAT1632Info(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 474);

            this.Signature = (ushort)Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr);
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 2);
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size=474, Pack=1)]
    internal struct FAT1632Info
    {
        // FAT16
        public byte FAT16_LogicalDriveNumber; // 36
        public byte FAT16_Reserved1; // 37
        public byte FAT16_ExtendedSignature; // 38
        public uint FAT16_PartitionSerialNumber; // 39
        public string FAT16_VolumeName; // 43
        public string FAT16_FSType; // 54
        public byte[] FAT16_Reserved2; // 62

        // FAT32
        public uint FAT32_SectorsPerFAT32; // 36
        public ushort FAT32_ExtFlags; // 40
        public ushort FAT32_FSVer; // 42
        public uint FAT32_RootDirStart; // 44
        public ushort FAT32_FSInfoSector; // 48
        public ushort FAT32_BackupBootSector; // 50
        public byte[] FAT32_Reserved1; // 52
        public byte FAT32_LogicalDriveNumber; // 64
        public byte FAT32_Reserved2; // 65
        public byte FAT32_ExtendedSignature; // 66
        public uint FAT32_PartitionSerialNumber; // 67
        public string FAT32_VolumeName; // 71
        public string FAT32_FSType; // 82
        public byte[] FAT32_Reserved3; // 90

        public FAT1632Info(IntPtr ptr)
        {
            int i;
            IntPtr startPtr = ptr;

            // FAT 16
            this.FAT16_LogicalDriveNumber = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr); // 0
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);

            this.FAT16_Reserved1 = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr); // 1
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);

            this.FAT16_ExtendedSignature = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr); // 2
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);

            this.FAT16_PartitionSerialNumber = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr); // 3
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 4);

            StringBuilder volName16 = new StringBuilder(11);

            for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                char c = (char)Marshal.ReadByte(ptr);
                volName16.Append(c);

                ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);
            }

            this.FAT16_VolumeName = volName16.ToString();

            StringBuilder fileSystemType16 = new StringBuilder(8);

            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                char c = (char)Marshal.ReadByte(ptr);
                fileSystemType16.Append(c);

                ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);
            }

            this.FAT16_FSType = fileSystemType16.ToString();

            this.FAT16_Reserved2 = new byte[448];

            for (i = 0; i < 448; i++)
            {
                this.FAT16_Reserved2[i] = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr);
                ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);
            }

            // FAT32
            ptr = startPtr;

            this.FAT32_SectorsPerFAT32 = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr); // 36, 4
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 4);

            this.FAT32_ExtFlags = (ushort)Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr); // 40, 2
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 2);

            this.FAT32_FSVer = (ushort)Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr); // 42, 2
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 2);

            this.FAT32_RootDirStart = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr); // 44, 4
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 4);

            this.FAT32_FSInfoSector = (ushort)Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr); // 48, 2
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 2);

            this.FAT32_BackupBootSector = (ushort)Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr); // 50, 2
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 2);

            this.FAT32_Reserved1 = new byte[12];  // 52, 12

            for (i=0;i<12;i++) 
            {
                this.FAT32_Reserved1[i] = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr);
                ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);
            }

            this.FAT32_LogicalDriveNumber = (byte)Marshal.ReadByte(ptr); // 64, 1
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);

            this.FAT32_Reserved2 = (byte)Marshal.ReadByte(ptr); // 65, 1
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);

            this.FAT32_ExtendedSignature = (byte)Marshal.ReadByte(ptr); // 66, 1
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);

            this.FAT32_PartitionSerialNumber = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr); // 67, 1
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 4);

            StringBuilder volName32 = new StringBuilder(11); // 71, 11

            for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                char c = (char)Marshal.ReadByte(ptr);
                volName32.Append(c);
                ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);
            }

            this.FAT32_VolumeName = volName32.ToString();

            StringBuilder fileSystemType32 = new StringBuilder(8);   // 82, 8

            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                char c = (char)Marshal.ReadByte(ptr);
                fileSystemType32.Append(c);
                ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);
            }

            this.FAT32_FSType = fileSystemType32.ToString();

            this.FAT32_Reserved3 = new byte[420]; // 90, 420

            for (i = 0; i < 420; i++)
            {
                this.FAT32_Reserved3[i] = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr);
                ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

I do however like the good explanation left by David on why it doesn't work as it should so I will accept that as the answer and leave this here for the future when somebody else is running into the same problem I am having trying to read the FAT boot sector in C#.

Comment: It's really not that hard to write it as a struct and avoid all this gnarly code.